# Why cannot WPS PDF add a note/annotation in Bengali language?

Tags: fonts, pdf, language-support, wps-office

I can add a note or annotation in **English** language while reading a *pdf* file in **WPS PDF**. But when I try to add a note in **Bengali** language some square boxes appear instead of showing it in **Bengali**.

Besides, if the title of the *pdf* file is in **Bengali**, it also shows some boxes instead of showing the actual **Bengali** text.

I tried Changing the font (which supports **Bengali**, e.g. ***Jamrul***) in settings, but it didn't work.

Now, I don't know wheather this problem occurs with other languages. I installed **WPS OFFICE** from the original *deb* file downloaded from the [official website](https://linux.wps.com/).

***Special Note:*** I am able to write in **Bengali** in WPS Writer, LibreOffice Writer and Notepadqq.

Comment: Is the **fonts-noto-core** package, which includes a Bengali font, installed on your system?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It is not installed, but I can write Bengali in WPS Writer or in LibreOffice Writer.

Comment: Maybe a WPS bug then.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Hey, I just installed **fonts-noto-core**, but it didn't work!

Comment: Are you using ibus-avro to write Bengali? I last tried writing Bengali with ibus-avro in WPS office in 2016, and it showed square boxes. It must be a WPS bug. I have also tried Onlyoffice. It also has issues with rendering Bengali fonts correctly. But Libreoffice renders it perfectly.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I am not using ibus-avro, I am giving input from my android phone's keyboard (which is using UNIJOY) via KDE Connect. I also tried copying Bengali text from other sources, but it didn't work. It must be a WPS bug! I don't like LibreOffice and OnlyOffice because they are not as user friendly and feature-rich as WPS Office.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how to make WPS office annotate PDF files in Bangla, I know that Evince (GNOME's default pdf reader) can do that (with `ibus-avro`).
[image]

Okular (KDE's default pdf reader) has excellend PDF annotation support, and it support Bangla.
[image]

Comment: I can annotate in Bangla in Okular, qpdfview and Foxit reader. But I want to do it in WPS PDF, because I like it the most for the other functionalities it provide.